# how to delete a numpy array: Chasing memory grow

Tags: python, numpy, astronomy

I am manipulating large astronomical images. I have memory growth as I process more images. When I am finished processing an image/array, can I delete it and how?  I use matplotlib plt.close('all') for the plots. Is there anything similar for np arrays? Should I just recycle it by emptying it maybe to save delete/create cycles?

python3.8, ubuntu 20.04, numpy, astronomy

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

`del arr`

it's a kind of garbage collecting.
You can also you [garbage_collect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html)

Comment: del arr seems the logical way to go, I'll try it. Thx

Comment: if you dont need further help please accept the answer so this question can be closed